# Parse json with different types value (Newtonsoft.Json)

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, json.net

Help me parse the `json` with `Newtonsoft.Json`.

```
  {
    "_id": 160,
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [43.59043144045182, 39.72119003534317]
    },  
},
{
    "_id": 161, 
    "location": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [43.58780105200211, 39.719191789627075],
            [43.58817794899264, 39.719465374946594]
        ]
    },  
},
{
    "_id": 152, 
        "location": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [43.590524759627954, 39.71930980682373],
                [43.590474249766544, 39.71926689147949],
                [43.59043151061995, 39.71934735774994],
                [43.59073456936772, 39.71958339214325],
                [43.59076565222992, 39.71949219703674]
            ]
        },
}
```

Key `coordinates` has type `List<double>` or `List<List<double>>` depending on the key `type` (Polygon, LineString, Point).

Comment: What have you tried? Also, have you looked at linq-to-json in json.net? It allows for what amounts to "manual" parsing using JObject/JArray which would let you decide how to interpret the `coordinates` field: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this problem using a custom `JsonConverter`.  The converter can load the data for each shape, look at the `type` field and then populate the coordinates array accordingly.  And actually, if you want, the converter can do double-duty here to flatten the data down into a simpler class structure while we're at it.  Here's how I would do it, given the JSON you have presented.

First, define a class to hold the deserialized shape data.  We'll deserialize into a list of these:

```
class Shape
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Next create the converter class.  This is responsible for transforming the JSON for each shape into a concrete `Shape` object.

```
class ShapeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Shape));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        Shape shape = new Shape();
        shape.Id = (int)jo["_id"];
        shape.Type = (string)jo["location"]["type"];
        JArray ja = (JArray)jo["location"]["coordinates"];
        if (shape.Type == "Point")
        {
            shape.Coordinates = new List<List<double>>();
            shape.Coordinates.Add(ja.ToObject<List<double>>());
        }
        else
        {
            shape.Coordinates = ja.ToObject<List<List<double>>>();
        }
        return shape;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to the `Shape` class to tie it to the `ShapeConverter`:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ShapeConverter))]
class Shape
{
    ...
}
```

All that is left is to deserialize the JSON, which we can do like this:

```
List<Shape> shapes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Shape>>(json);
```

Here is a test program to demonstrate:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        [
            {
                ""_id"": 160,
                ""location"": {
                    ""type"": ""Point"",
                    ""coordinates"": [ 43.59043144045182, 39.72119003534317 ]
                }
            },
            {
                ""_id"": 161,
                ""location"": {
                    ""type"": ""LineString"",
                    ""coordinates"": [
                        [ 43.58780105200211, 39.719191789627075 ],
                        [ 43.58817794899264, 39.719465374946594 ]
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                ""_id"": 152,
                ""location"": {
                    ""type"": ""Polygon"",
                    ""coordinates"": [
                        [ 43.590524759627954, 39.71930980682373 ],
                        [ 43.590474249766544, 39.71926689147949 ],
                        [ 43.59043151061995, 39.71934735774994 ],
                        [ 43.59073456936772, 39.71958339214325 ],
                        [ 43.59076565222992, 39.71949219703674 ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]";

        List<Shape> shapes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Shape>>(json);

        foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id: " + shape.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Type: " + shape.Type);
            Console.WriteLine("Coordinates: ");
            foreach (List<double> point in shape.Coordinates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("   (" + point[0] + ", " + point[1] + ")");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Id: 160
Type: Point
Coordinates:
   (43.5904314404518, 39.7211900353432)

Id: 161
Type: LineString
Coordinates:
   (43.5878010520021, 39.7191917896271)
   (43.5881779489926, 39.7194653749466)

Id: 152
Type: Polygon
Coordinates:
   (43.590524759628, 39.7193098068237)
   (43.5904742497665, 39.7192668914795)
   (43.59043151062, 39.7193473577499)
   (43.5907345693677, 39.7195833921433)
   (43.5907656522299, 39.7194921970367)
```

If you want to get more fancy, you can use a `Point` struct instead of a `List<double>` for each coordinate, and/or you can create an actual class hierarchy for each type of complex shape (e.g. Line, Polygon) and compose them of `Points`.  It would not be difficult to modify the converter to create these objects if desired.  I'll leave that part to you.