# Deserializing a weirdly shaped JSON object with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize following weirdly shaped JSON object into the class that makes much more sense.

```
{
    "item": {
        "article_title": {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "Title of article 1"
        },
        "content": {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "Article 1 content"
        },
        "related_articles": {
            "type": "related",
            "value": [
                "article2"
            ]
        }
    },
    "additional_items": {
        "article2": {
            "article_title": {
                "type": "text",
                "value": "Title of article 2"
            },
            "content": {
                "type": "text",
                "value": "Article 2 content"
            },
            "related_articles": {
                "type": "related",
                "value": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

deserialize into the following `Article` class

```
public class Article {
    public string ArticleTitle;
    public string Content;
    public List<Article> RelatedArticles;
}
```

The JSON has two properties in its root object. `Item` is the current item and `additional_items` property holds any other items that are referenced in `related_articles` property.

I was able to create a working solution based on JsonConverter solution described here [Parse json with different types value (Newtonsoft.Json)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466790/parse-json-with-different-types-value-newtonsoft-json), but that's not actually what I need. I have a lot of JSON responses similar to this one, and I don't want to write a Converter for every each of them. What I need is something that is able to resolve value based on property name (eg.g: For `<class-name>.<property-name>` look for the value in `item/<property-name>/value`)

Comment: You may need a custom converter.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com

Answer (score 0):

Use [SelectToken](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) and then use ToObject directly.

```
var article = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("item").ToObject<List<Article>>();
```

to deserialize you can do something like this

```
List<string[]> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: You're just trying to deserialize the JSON into a list?  Once this is done you can cycle through pulling out information needed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by transforming it into a new JObject containing only `"key":"value"` properties that could be easily parsed by newtonsoft.json

```
JObject fields = new JObject();
foreach (var property in ((JObject)response.SelectToken("$.item.elements")).Properties())
{
    // Remove underscore characters to support loading into PascalCase property names in CSharp code
    string propertyName = property.Name.Replace("_", "");
    fields.Add(propertyName, property.First["value"]);
}

return fields.ToObject<T>();
```